# Performance issue with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js

I am having performance bottleneck with Express.js.
The scenario is as follows. Client is Backbone/Marionette/RequireJS full SPA.Server is written in sails.js. Sails is being used only as a REST server (not serving any HTML) Both of those applications are served on one machine on AWS - Windows instance. WIndows server 2012 32x.

Sails is served as separate node proccess. Client is served as another separate process. Server response time is instant, while client is horrible. The *.js files are constantly downloaded again and again. Here is the script that I use only to serve Client.

```
    "use strict";



process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept');

    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};

var path = require("path"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express();

app.configure('production', function () {
    var oneYear = 31557600000;         //31557600000
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    app.use(app.router);
    //Serve the root
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../',  { maxAge: oneYear } ));
    console.log("Started!");
});

app.listen(80)
```

1. Is there anything wrong with this minimalistic Express server as it is?
   This script is in folder which is located in the root of the project.
2. Am I going to get better results if I serve these scripts with Apache? IIS? Using anything other then node, kinda defeats the purpose I guess... but I am willing to do anything to finally resolve this problem. If it is perfectly valid to serve my Client using IIS, then so be it. I just need directions.

The same project when started on Ubuntu instance (which I cant use) is much faster, they used Apache to serve Backbone Client. Response time is great. And theirs and ours instance is served on Micro instance.

When I enlarge instance (Windows), say something like M1.Medium, then everything is much better and faster. Certainly we will use payed instances for the project... it is just incredible that Ubuntu instance runs much faster then the Windows one. Maybe that is normal, since Windows Server has bigger memory and CPU footprint? I just don't know.

Any thoughts on this?